# How can I sort a dataframe by the order of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. `eval_df` and `uneval_df`.

`eval_df` looks like this:

```
      sentiment            id                       date                                               text
0             0  5.400000e+17  2014-12-03 07:01:05+00:00  conniempp wwi began in sarajevo wwiii to begin...
1             0  1.320000e+18  2020-10-24 17:05:38+00:00  nsheth4 janet63388900 alivelshi pretty sure yo...
2             0  6.420000e+17  2015-09-11 16:33:44+00:00  immigration is stressful for all immigrants go...
3             0  1.080000e+18  2019-01-07 15:39:48+00:00  motorcitihawk relbtx ingrahamangle wolfblitzer...
4             1  4.360000e+17  2014-02-20 02:41:36+00:00  christiisilvaxx you can get somethin better wi...
...         ...           ...                        ...                                                ...
62744         0  1.310000e+18  2020-09-14 15:58:18+00:00  seminoles78 grandpasnarky they buy in to the i...
62745         0  1.470000e+18  2021-12-17 02:27:04+00:00  michelecomstoc1 farmerrick potus 2this resulte...
62746         0  1.280000e+18  2020-06-22 16:09:31+00:00  i have this lady on the phone and her english ...
62747         0  1.140000e+18  2019-06-13 03:21:33+00:00  food just has not been the same since i left v...
62748         0  1.280000e+18  2020-07-18 00:02:24+00:00  half of this country was mexico and was built ...
```

And `uneval_df` looks like this:

```
      sentiment            id                       date                                               text
0             0  7.471049e+17  2016-06-26 16:31:07+00:00  if 12 million immigrants from mexico will help...
1             0  8.338858e+17  2017-02-21 03:47:19+00:00  russian immigrants in minnesota are perplexed ...
2             0  1.227999e+18  2020-02-13 16:52:33+00:00  washingtonpost gather prison all near border b...
3             0  1.346244e+18  2021-01-04 23:57:07+00:00  serenitydogg sethabramson i hope he runs to ru...
4             0  6.356885e+17  2015-08-24 05:42:03+00:00  realdonaldtrump doesnt matter if our parents m...
...         ...           ...                        ...                                                ...
62744         0  1.572305e+18  2022-09-20 19:21:44+00:00  real original americans the native american in...
62745         0  1.374097e+18  2021-03-22 20:34:53+00:00  fairness bill is good for america silence is n...
62746         0  6.664505e+17  2015-11-17 02:59:04+00:00  if christians are still in syria why are they ...
62747         0  1.373095e+18  2021-03-20 02:11:41+00:00  mbachelet no to ethiopia human right commissio...
62748         0  9.221188e+17  2017-10-22 15:13:54+00:00  scottyhasty jbouie hahah and i bet you think i...
```

`eval_df` is in a particular, random order that should not be changed How can I sort `uneval_df` by the same order as `eval_df` such that the rows are in the same order ?

Desired outcome: I want `uneval_df` to look like this:

```
      sentiment            id                       date                                               text
0             0  5.400000e+17  2014-12-03 07:01:05+00:00  began in sarajevo to begin...
1             0  1.320000e+18  2020-10-24 17:05:38+00:00  alivelshi pretty sure yo...
2             0  6.420000e+17  2015-09-11 16:33:44+00:00  immigration is stressful for all immigrants go...
3             0  1.080000e+18  2019-01-07 15:39:48+00:00  wow that was cool
4             0  4.360000e+17  2014-02-20 02:41:36+00:00  you can get somethin better wi...
...         ...           ...                        ...                                                ...
62744         0  1.310000e+18  2020-09-14 15:58:18+00:00  they buy in to the i...
62745         0  1.470000e+18  2021-12-17 02:27:04+00:00  2this resulted in something...
62746         0  1.280000e+18  2020-06-22 16:09:31+00:00  i have this lady on the phone and her english ...
62747         0  1.140000e+18  2019-06-13 03:21:33+00:00  food just has not been the same since i left v...
62748         0  1.280000e+18  2020-07-18 00:02:24+00:00  half of this country was mexico and was built ...
```

I have tried sorting by the following statement:

```
uneval_df = uneval_df.sort_values(by=eval_df['id'])
```

But this returned the following error:

```
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 0        5.400000e+17
1        1.320000e+18
2        6.420000e+17
3        1.080000e+18
4        4.360000e+17
             ...     
62744    1.310000e+18
62745    1.470000e+18
62746    1.280000e+18
62747    1.140000e+18
62748    1.280000e+18
Name: id, Length: 62749, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
eval_df =eval_df.set_index('id')
eval_df = eval_df.reindex(index=uneval_df['id'])
```

Comment: It looks like the program thinks that there are duplicate 'id' labels because the string for them, since it is rounding the value due to the string being very long. Is there a way to work around that?